# How can I export opentelemetry data into a file without a backend collector for testing

Tags: c#, open-telemetry

I have a c# application using OpenTelemetry.

There are different exporters for different backend collectors (like Jaeger)

But in my dev environment, there is no such backend service set up.

Although I can use console exporter, but it will be mixed with my other messages.

I also tried Otlp Exporter

```
.AddOtlpExporter(options => options.Endpoint = new Uri(@"C:\temp\a.txt"))
```

but returns the following error

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Endpoint URI scheme (file) is not supported. Currently only "http" and "https" are supported.'
```

It seems that a file schema is not supported at the moment.

Is there any way I can simply output it to a file for easy testing and debugging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always write your own exporter.
it should be fairly simple to implement, you can use the console exporter as a template and just write to a file instead of the console.

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console/ConsoleActivityExporter.cs

Comment: never thought about this way, but seems exactly what I am looking for. I can also refer to this (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console/ConsoleExporterHelperExtensions.cs) for the AddXXXExporter extension method. Thanks very much.

Comment: @kzfid Did you end up doing this? Is it available anywhere?

Comment: Hi @PaulBiggar, Yes. Basically, you need to have your own classes for these 2 files https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console/ConsoleActivityExporter.cs and https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console/ConsoleExporterHelperExtensions.cs. I did not post my new ones online.

Comment: What about visualizing from the file? Wouldn’t be nice to “import” the file to Jaeger or Zip?